# Enviar una variable al template en Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Tengo una vista con un buscador y varios tabs. Dependiendo lo que busque obtengo resultados en los distintos tabs.

En el archivo search.php tengo lo siguiente:

```
$totalResults = 0;

$return = array();


$results = $user->search_quick($_POST['query']);

if($results) {

    foreach($results as $key=>$value) {
        $totalResults++;
    }

    $smarty->assign('results', $results);
    $smarty->assign('totalResults', $totalResults);

    $return['results'] = $smarty->fetch('ajax.search.tpl');

}

return_json($return);
```

En la clase users tengo esta función:

```
public function search_quick($query) {

    global $db, $system;

    $results = [];

    /* search users */

    $get_users = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT user_id, user_name, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_gender, user_picture, user_subscribed, user_verified FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE %1$s OR user_firstname LIKE %1$s OR user_lastname LIKE %1$s OR CONCAT(user_firstname,  " ", user_lastname) LIKE %1$s LIMIT %2$s', secure($query, 'search'), secure($system['min_results'], 'int', false) )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

    if($get_users->num_rows > 0) {

        while($user = $get_users->fetch_assoc()) {

            $user['user_picture'] = get_picture($user['user_picture'], $user['user_gender']);

            /* get the connection between the viewer & the target */

            $user['connection'] = $this->connection($user['user_id']);

            $user['sort'] = $user['user_firstname'];

            $user['type'] = 'user';

            $results[] = $user;

        }

    }

    /* search pages */

    $get_pages = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_name LIKE %1$s OR page_title LIKE %1$s LIMIT %2$s', secure($query, 'search'), secure($system['min_results'], 'int', false) )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

    if($get_pages->num_rows > 0) {

        while($page = $get_pages->fetch_assoc()) {

            $page['page_picture'] = get_picture($page['page_picture'], 'page');

            /* check if the viewer liked the page */

            $page['i_like'] = $this->check_page_membership($this->_data['user_id'], $page['page_id']);

            $page['sort'] = $page['page_title'];

            $page['type'] = 'page';

            $results[] = $page;

        }

    }

    /* search groups */

    $get_groups = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE group_privacy != "secret" AND (group_name LIKE %1$s OR group_title LIKE %1$s) LIMIT %2$s', secure($query, 'search'), secure($system['min_results'], 'int', false) )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

    if($get_groups->num_rows > 0) {

        while($group = $get_groups->fetch_assoc()) {

            $group['group_picture'] = get_picture($group['group_picture'], 'group');

            /* check if the viewer joined the group */

            $group['i_joined'] = $this->check_group_membership($this->_data['user_id'], $group['group_id']);

            $group['sort'] = $group['group_title'];

            $group['type'] = 'group';

            $results[] = $group;

        }

    }

    /* search events */

    $get_events = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE event_privacy != "secret" AND event_title LIKE %1$s LIMIT %2$s', secure($query, 'search'), secure($system['min_results'], 'int', false) )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

    if($get_events->num_rows > 0) {

        while($event = $get_events->fetch_assoc()) {

            $event['event_picture'] = get_picture($event['event_cover'], 'event');

            /* check if the viewer joined the event */

            $event['i_joined'] = $this->check_event_membership($this->_data['user_id'], $event['event_id']);

            $event['sort'] = $event['event_title'];

            $event['type'] = 'event';

            $results[] = $event;

        }

    }

    /* sort results */

    function sort_results($a, $b){

        return strcmp($a["sort"], $b["sort"]);

    }

    usort($results, 'sort_results');

    return $results;

}
```

Y en el template search.tpl:

```
<div class="tab-content">
                    
    <!-- all -->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
    {if $totalResults > 1}
        <ul>
            {foreach $results['posts'] as $post}
            {include file='__feeds_post.tpl'}
            {/foreach}
            {foreach $results['articles'] as $post}
            {include file='__feeds_post.tpl'}
            {/foreach}
            {foreach $results['users'] as $_user}
            {include file='__feeds_user.tpl' _tpl="list" _connection=$_user['connection']}
            {/foreach}
            {foreach $results['pages'] as $_page}
            {include file='__feeds_page.tpl' _tpl="list"}
            {/foreach}
            {foreach $results['groups'] as $_group}
            {include file='__feeds_group.tpl' _tpl="list"}
            {/foreach}
            {foreach $results['events'] as $_event}
            {include file='__feeds_event.tpl' _tpl="list"}
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {else}
        <div class="text-center text-muted mtb10">
            <img width="25%" src="{$system['system_url']}/content/themes/{$system['theme']}/images/no_results.png">
            <p class="mt10 mb10"><strong>{__("No results to show")}</strong></p>
        </div>
    {/if}
    </div>
    <!-- all -->
                    
    <!-- posts -->
    <div class="tab-panel" id="posts">
    {if count($results['posts']) > 0}
    <ul>
        {foreach $results['posts'] as $post}
            {include file='__feeds_post.tpl'}
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
    {else}
        <div class="text-center text-muted mtb10">
            <img width="25%" src="{$system['system_url']}/content/themes/{$system['theme']}/images/no_results.png">
            <p class="mt10 mb10"><strong>{__("No results to show")}</strong></p>
        </div>
    {/if}
    </div>
    <!-- posts -->

    <!-- blogs -->
   {if $system['blogs_enabled']}
       <div class="tab-pane" id="articles">
       {if count($results['articles']) > 0}
           <ul>
               {foreach $results['articles'] as $post}
                   {include file='__feeds_post.tpl'}
               {/foreach}
           </ul>
       {else}
           <div class="text-center text-muted mtb10">
               <img width="25%" src="{$system['system_url']}/content/themes/{$system['theme']}/images/no_results.png">
               <p class="mt10 mb10"><strong>{__("No results to show")}</strong></p>
           </div>
       {/if}
       </div>
   {/if}
   <!-- blogs -->

   /* Y lo mismo con users, pages, groups y events */
```

La función return_json:

```
function return_json($response = array()) {

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    exit(json_encode($response));

}
```

Al hacer una busqueda, me muestra los posibles resultados en los respectivos tabs, pero en el tab All no me muestra el total de resultados, o sea, el conjunto de resultados de todos los tabs. No estaría llegando la variable $totalResults al template.

De seguro algo estoy haciendo mal. Si pudieran ayudarme, se los agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución: al final no se trataba de enviar el $totalResults del php al template, sino de crear la variable en el mismo .tpl usando la sintaxis de Smarty.

En search.php eliminé el foreach y las lineas con la variable $totalResults. Quedó así:

```
$return = array();

$results = $user->search_quick($_POST['query']);

if($results) {

    $smarty->assign('results', $results);

    $return['results'] = $smarty->fetch('ajax.search.tpl');

}

return_json($return);
```

Y en el template search.tpl agregué:

```
{$totalResults = 0}
{$totalResults = count($results['posts']) + count($results['articles']) + count($results['users']) + count($results['pages']) + count($results['groups']) + count($results['events'])}
```